# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: register too many Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, illegalargumentexception, huawei-mobile-services

I'm getting an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` with the following message `regist too many Broadcast Receivers` (yes, the message says `regist` and not `register`) when trying to get the latest `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` sticky intent.
I use the following code:

```
Intent latestStickyIntent = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

As you can see, there is no actual register of a new receiver since i'm using `null` as the BroadcastReceiver.

As far as I can see, this only happens for a single user on a HUAWEI RIO L01 device but I can't say if that's the cause.

Anyone had a similar experience with that error?

**UPDATE (03/2016):**

Started seeing the same issue on other Huawei devices (ALE L04, G7 L03) but still no devices from other manufacturers.

[image]

Comment: You have clarified if he uses a custom rom?

Comment: just for interest: why You are passing null instead of a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs registering a null receiver only gets you the latest sticky without actually registering a new receiver

Comment: pff...sorry, if had read the question carefully, I hadn´t to aks :).....

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on HUAWEI RIO L01 but using the Glide library because under the hood it uses a broadcast receiver to monitor the connectivity changes. Obliviously this is an issue in the Huawei code.

Comment: Recently, I saw a couple of similar reports too. And I also use Glide by the way. I'm curious if @Muzikant uses Glide too.

Here is the thread on Glide about the issue https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1161

Comment: @Gregory not using Glide. This happens in my code

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue. Again with 100% Huawei devices and %100 Android 5.1.X

(not using Glide)

Comment: For our app: Manufactuer: 95% Huawei, 5% Samsung. OS: 97% 5, 3% 6

Comment: Have you found any solution? We don't use Glide and have this issue on Huawei devices.

Comment: any news on this error log?

Answer (score 4):

This is the confine of huawei's mobile phone system. Huawei's mobile phone has a white list mechanism. Only the APP in their white list can avoid this bug. I use reflection to try to solve this bug. may help for you

https://github.com/llew2011/HuaWeiVerifier

### How to usage

```
dependencies {
    // add dependencies
    implementation 'com.llew.huawei:verifier:1.0.2'
}


public class SimpleApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LoadedApkHuaWei.hookHuaWeiVerifier(getBaseContext());
    }
}
```

### That all

Comment: I saw this error on firebase now. And it is huawei.